# Open Android app as a fresh launch via URL intent, when app is in background

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have a hybrid application, with a base activity hosting multiple fragments.

I am trying to open the app, from another app with the use of URL intent; declaring intent filters for the base activity in the Android Manifest.

When the app opens from background, I do use the Fragment manager to pop all fragments.

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

```
for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

But still the app does not open like a fresh launch!

Is it possible simulate a fresh launch in this scenario?

PS - I have some configurations in the onCreate class, so I am bound to use the onResume method to simulate this effect!